# How to get double quotes in Scrapy .csv results

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a problem with quotations within outputs using Scrapy. I am trying to scrap data that contains commas and this results in double quotations in some columns like so:

```
TEST,TEST,TEST,ON,TEST,TEST,"$2,449,000, 4,735 Sq Ft, 6 Bed, 5.1 Bath, Listed 03/01/2016"
TEST,TEST,TEST,ON,TEST,TEST,"$2,895,000, 4,975 Sq Ft, 5 Bed, 4.1 Bath, Listed 01/03/2016"
```

Only columns with commas get double quoted. How can I double quote all my data columns?

I want Scrapy to output:

```
"TEST","TEST","TEST","ON","TEST","TEST","$2,449,000, 4,735 Sq Ft, 6 Bed, 5.1 Bath, Listed 03/01/2016"
"TEST","TEST","TEST","ON","TEST","TEST","$2,895,000, 4,975 Sq Ft, 5 Bed, 4.1 Bath, Listed 01/03/2016"
```

Are there any settings I can change to do this?

Answer (score 5):

By default, for CSV output, Scrapy uses [`csv.writer()` with the defaults](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/exporters.py#L187).

For fields quotes, [the default is csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quoting):

> Instructs writer objects to only quote those fields which contain
>   special characters such as delimiter, quotechar or any of the
>   characters in lineterminator.

But you can build your own CSV item exporter and set a new dialect, building on the default `'excel'` dialect.

For example, in an `exporters.py` module, define the following

```
import csv

from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter


class QuoteAllDialect(csv.excel):
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL


class QuoteAllCsvItemExporter(CsvItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update({'dialect': QuoteAllDialect})
        super(QuoteAllCsvItemExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you simply need to [reference this item exporter in your settings](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exporters) for CSV output, something like:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'myproject.exporters.QuoteAllCsvItemExporter',
}
```

And a simple spider like this:

```
import scrapy


class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://example.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {
            "name": "Some name",
            "title": "Some title, baby!",
            "description": "Some description, with commas, quotes (\") and all"
        }
```

will output this:

```
"description","name","title"
"Some description, with commas, quotes ("") and all","Some name","Some title, baby!"
```